# Poner un valor por defecto en el formulario de crear en MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-4

estoy tratando de poner un valor por defecto en el formulario de crear en ASP.NET MVC, El valor por defecto sera cero, pero el usuario puede modificar ese valor y agregarle el numero que el desee.

pero cuando intento enviar los datos para guardar el registro el formulario se queda frizado

mi codigo es mas o menos el siguiente:

en el controlador:

```
public ActionResult CreateNewMyEntity(string default_value)  { 
           MyEntity newMyEntity = new MyEntity(); 
           newMyEntity._propertyValue = default_value; 
           return View(newMyEntity); }
```

en la vista index:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Create New", "CreateNewMyEntity", new {
default_value = "0" })
```

Comment: qué error te está arrojando? todo parece estar bien

Comment: cuando le doy a guardar cambios al formulario, no avanza, y no me marca ningún error, pero no me guarda los campos

Comment: ¿Está definido en la ruta el valor de `default_value`? Mira tu startup.cs y revisa las rutas, a veces se olvidan de leer la documentación y por eso ese valor siempre llega null.

Comment: muchas gracias chicos, al final era un error que tenia porque no había actualizado el modelo de datos.

Comment: lo pude resolver de una manera mas facil que la que estaba intentando inicialmente: